# обойти overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Есть блок. Имеет вид строки таблицы с ячейками. К этому блоку применен горизонтальный скролл.
в чем проблема?

при Нажатии на последний блок(ячейку) этой строки, появляется дропдаун.
При появлении дропдауна появляется вертикальный скролл, а сам дропдаун прячется при выходе за пределы родителя

```
.scroll-container
    .headerTable
    .contentTable
        .wrapperItem
            .tableItem
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                .item-ItemTable
                    .wrapper-drop
                        .icon
                        .actionDropDown
    .scroll-x
    .scroll-y
```

все элементы div'ы

Comment: Надо добавить код. Решений может быть несколько, зависят от вашей реализации таблицы.

Comment: К сожалению, приведенный код никак не помогает понять, что у вас там происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас применен скролл (а точнее, `overflow | overflow-x`, отличный от `visible`). 
Как только к элементу по одному направлению применен оверфлоу, отличный от `visible`, элемент получает свойство оверфлоу `auto` по оставшемуся. Т.е., если вы задали, например, `overflow-x:hidden`, то элемент начнет себя вести как `overflow-y:auto` и поэтому когда его содержимое начнет становиться больше его самого, будет появляться внутренний скроллинг.

Чтобы содержимое элемента выходило за его пределы, элемент должен иметь свойства `overflow-x:visible; overflow-y:visible;` (это свойства дивов по умолчанию, если что). И, да, абсолютное позиционирование тут не поможет.

Если у вас возникла необходимость чтобы контейнер скроллился по одному направлению, но вел себя как `overflow:visible` по другому, вам придется хорошенько поизвращаться с дополнительными элементами и скриптами... ну или сделать изначально по-человечески - так, чтобы подобной необходимости не возникало.